# make table with average (mean) based on repeated column values of a data frame

Tags: r, average, mean

I have a table like this :

[image]

and i would like to calculate the average of mean values for each column in table one  for the same start and ends in order to have a table like this :

[image]

Can you tell me how to do this table in R ?

Comment: Try `aggregate(. ~ chr + i.start + i.end + coverage_con, df, mean)`

Comment: a good practice when you share your data is to copy and paste a **print** of the dataframes, instead of images. it's too hard to reproduce it since we cannot copy and paste it..

Comment: @DarrenTsai the call to `aggregate` is much mor concise then rodolfoksveiga s long pipe plus it does not need extra packages. Could you please make that an answer so I can upvote that?

Comment: thanks @DarrenTsai, i already gave you a like.. because both your solutions are smart. and `summarize_all()` is the way!

Comment: @Bernhard, `agreegate()` is more concise, but not as much efficient as `summarize()`, from **dplyr**..

Comment: @rodolfoksveiga Yes, there are certainly many aspects that go into that choice and if the data are so big, that time taken for aggregation is of concern, dplyr is among the better options in R.

Comment: @rodolfoksveiga you are right! `summarize()` is more efficient in large data than `aggregate()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering that your dataframe was called `df`, you can do:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(chr, i.start, i.end, coverage_con) %>%
  summarize_all(mean)
```

Answer (score 3):

A `base` solution with `aggregate()`:

```
aggregate(. ~ chr + i.start + i.end + coverage_con, df, mean)
```

The `dplyr` version:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(chr, i.start, i.end, coverage_con) %>%
  summarise(across(.fns = mean, .names = "average_{col}"))
```

`summarise(across(.fns = mean))` is equivalent to `summarise_all(mean)`, but the former can adjust column names by the ***glue specification***.

---

If the data include other non-numeric columns except those grouped ones, you can calculate means only on those numeric columns by `where()`, i.e.

```
... %>%
  summarise(across(where(is.numeric), mean, .names = "average_{col}"))
```

which is equivalent to `summarise_if(is.numeric, mean)`.

Comment: this `summarize()` coupled with **.names** is very elegant. thanks for sharing!